# Chained then not working in correct order

Tags: javascript, firebase

I just learnt about chained 'then' in Javascript but I'm facing an issue that the last then block executes before the previous then block has completed. 
Relevant code is:

```
firebaseRef.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            //getting key of the child
            var pid=childSnapshot.key;
            // childData will be the actual contents of the child
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            var name=childData.name;
            pids.push(pid);
            names.push(name);
    });
})
    .then(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < pids.length; i++) {
            $("#pid"+(i+1)).text(pids[i]);
            $("#name"+(i+1)).text(names[i]);
        }
        set1();
        set2();
        set3();
        set4();
    })
    .then(function(){
        calcAvg();
    });
```

Here, the calcAvg() fires off before the set1(), set2(), set3(), set4() methods have executed. This is giving me incorrect results. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

EDIT1: Please check the checkAvg() method here: https://jsfiddle.net/jek9m7hn/. Looks like there some issue due to it.

Comment: What do `set1-4()` and `calcAvg()` do? Can you post this code for us to examine?

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/jek9m7hn/. I have added code for set1() and calcAvg(). set2(), set3(), set4() are similar to set1(). Do let me know if you find anything.

Comment: @torazaburo I tried putting an alert statement in calcAvg and saw that the alert executed before the setn functions. Also, I'm setting values in setn() and then calculating their averages in calcAvg(). Since the calcAvg executes before setn executes, I'm getting the average values as NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `set1` is calling firebase API which is async. 
You should use `Promise.all` in your set methods to make sure all promises are resolved, something like this:

```
function set1() {
   ... // calculate stuff
   var p1 = guideRef.child("presentation").once('value');
   p1.then(...).
   ... // more calculations

   return Promise.all([p1, p2, ...]) // all your async calls
}
```

then, in your main function your could do something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pids.length; i++) {
   $("#pid"+(i+1)).text(pids[i]);
   $("#name"+(i+1)).text(names[i]);
}

return Promise.all([set1(), set2(), set3(), set4()])
```

I do think that refactoring your code can reduce this complexity, but this is out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

`set1` etc. operate asynchronously, but you are not waiting for them to complete. You need to rewrite `set1` to return a promise for when all the asynchronous work is done, then change your code to something like

```
 .then(set1).then(set2).then(set3).then(set4).then(calcAvg)
```

However, I would recommend re-writing all this code. You should not really be using the DOM as the main place to store values. Also, you should combine the firebase calls instead of making a separate call for each individual value.

Answer (score -1):

Variables declared inside function of one then cannot be accessed inside the function of a chained then. A variable inside JS has a block scope, there by variable declared in one block scope cannot be accessed inside another block scope. To deal with your problem, you can try declaring pid outside of the first then, i.e. refactor your code as follows

```
var pids = [], names = [];
firebaseRef.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            //getting key of the child
            var pid=childSnapshot.key;
            // childData will be the actual contents of the child
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            var name=childData.name;
            pids.push(pid);
            names.push(name);
    });
})
    .then(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < pids.length; i++) {
            $("#pid"+(i+1)).text(pids[i]);
            $("#name"+(i+1)).text(names[i]);
        }
        set1();
        set2();
        set3();
        set4();
    })
    .then(function(){
        calcAvg();
    });
```

Comment: How does this explain the behavior which the OP claims to be observing, or fix it? Your code is likely to result in a reference error, since `pid` is not declared anywhere now.